# Can't vote to close on a specific question

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I tried to vote to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861973/a-class-i-wrote-seem-not-to-access-some-private-fields-of-another-class-that-are).

I got this close page :

[image]

As you can see, I can't choose a close reason, or do anything except clicking the `x`.
I tried to cast a close vote on another question, and the other question didn't have that problem. The original question still does.

Comment: That usually means you've already voted-to-close on it.

Comment: You missed the big bold header: ***You have already voted to close this question*** :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already voted to close on that question.

Now that it's closed it's evident. You voted and forgot about it :D

Comment: Yes, I feel really stupid now. I voted to close it earlier and forgot. Perhaps that window should say that I already voted to close it (and perhaps even allow me to cancel my vote if I change my mind). Should I delete the question, or is it too late for that?

Comment: @Eran It does say that you already voted right at the top. :)

Comment: @Eran: Accept and move on, accept and move on... :P

Comment: The text "You have already voted to close the question" is written in big letters on top of the message box. What else do you need?

Comment: @TronicZomB Now I feel stupid and blind :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Accepted, and thanks to the down-voter, my total rep change is 0, so I can pretend I never posted this question :).

Comment: Well, that's not true anymore :)